# Clear gap between span and table

Tags: html, css

**[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trad1qkh/)**

I added a span right after the first table, but it didn't work as i expected, there is a gap between the table and the span, and the span width does not conform the first table's width too

This is the css for the span:

```
.tieudecuoi
{
    line-height:24px;
    background-color: #80A5CE;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-top:0px;
    padding-bottom: 0; 
    width:300px !important;
}
```

[image]

**[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trad1qkh/)**

Comment: Try using a <div> instead of a span.

Comment: @stubailo a div will cause this : http://pik.vn/20142d237b36-7ce8-488d-91f9-4b45ef3051fb.jpeg

Comment: remove line-height from your css

Comment: @Urielzen doesn't work, you can visit the jsfiddle link I posted,  Thanks alot!

Comment: I did, it works for me, at least it moves up a little bit. You can additionally try adding    position: relative;top: -4px;

Comment: @Urielzen ok now, and one more question please, how about the width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me, like I mentioned in the comments, but I just tested it in Chrome...

**EDIT**: I changed the aproach a little bit, I am not sure if this is something you can do in your project, but if you do, it will give you the desire result. Please let me know if this is doable for you.

```css
      .tieudecuoi {
        background-color: #80A5CE;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #FFF;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 12px;
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        padding-top: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 0;
    }
    body {
    }

    table, th, td, tr {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border: 1px solid;
    }

    .tb {
        width: 500px;
    }

    /*2 cell đầu tiên, xác định độ rộng*/

    .tdkq {
        width: 70%;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    .tddd {
        width: 30%;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    /*bảng kết quả và đầu đuôi*/

    .tbkq {
        width: 100%;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        table-layout: fixed;
        float: left;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
    }

    .tbdd {
        width: 100%;
    }

    /*cột giải và kết quả của bảng kết quả*/

    .trkq {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .thkqgiai {
        width: 20% !important;
    }

    .thkqso {
        width: 80% !important;
    }

    .tdkqgiai {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .tdkqso {
        text-align: center;
        word-wrap: break-word !important;
    }

    /*cột đầu và đuôi của bảng đầu đuôi*/

    .thdddau {
        width: 30%;
    }

    .thddduoi {
        width: 70%;
    }

    /*tiêu đề cho bảng kq*/
    .tieudemien {
        line-height: 24px;
        background-color: #80A5CE;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #FFF;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 12px;
        width: 500px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
    }
```

```html
<h2 class="tieudemien"> Kết quả xổ số Miền Bắc ngày 02-11-2014</h2>
<table class="tb">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="tdkq">
                <table class="tbkq">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="trkq">
                            <th class="thkqgiai">Giải</th>
                            <th class="thkqso">BTB</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tdkqgiai">Đặc biệt</td>
                            <td class="tdkqso">23411</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tdkqgiai">Giải nhất</td>
                            <td class="tdkqso">37428</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tdkqgiai">Giải nh&#236;</td>
                            <td class="tdkqso">38460-75356</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tdkqgiai">Giải ba</td>
                            <td class="tdkqso">02055-66542-36814-52154-66881-20546</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tdkqgiai">Giải bốn</td>
                            <td class="tdkqso">6300-7736-6062-3408</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tdkqgiai">Giải năm</td>
                            <td class="tdkqso">0235-2078-1344-6340-4550-6337</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tdkqgiai">Giải s&#225;u</td>
                            <td class="tdkqso">046-421-944</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tdkqgiai">Giải bảy</td>
                            <td class="tdkqso">88-98-24-21</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" class="tieudecuoi">
                                spadfj lkj lkj lkj lkj lkj lkj lkj lkj lkj lkj lkj lkj lkjn

                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td class="tddd">
                <table class="tbdd">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="trkq">
                            <th class="thdddau">Đầu</th>
                            <th class="thddduoi">Đuôi</th>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td class="tdkqgiai">0</td>
                            <td class="tdkqso">0,8</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tdkqgiai">1</td>
                            <td class="tdkqso">1,4</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tdkqgiai">2</td>
                            <td class="tdkqso">8,1,4,1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tdkqgiai">3</td>
                            <td class="tdkqso">6,5,7</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tdkqgiai">4</td>
                            <td class="tdkqso">2,6,4,0,6,4</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tdkqgiai">5</td>
                            <td class="tdkqso">6,5,4,0</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tdkqgiai">6</td>
                            <td class="tdkqso">0,2</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tdkqgiai">7</td>
                            <td class="tdkqso">8</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tdkqgiai">8</td>
                            <td class="tdkqso">1,8</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tdkqgiai">9</td>
                            <td class="tdkqso">8</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, how about the width? How do I make it equal to the first table's width?